# Console.log(response) работает правильно, но хук состояния не устанавливает response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, асинхронность, promise

```
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState({})

const response = await (!isEdit || typeof project.id !== 'number'
   ? postProjectAdd(projectBody)
   : putProjectUpdate(project.id, projectBody));

console.log('response', response)
setResponseData(response)
console.log('responseData', responseData)
```

Что нужно исправить, чтобы `responseData` устанавливал такое же значение, как response?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setResponseData меняет состояние после консоли, это асинхронный метод